# Bottom 3 courses of cinder block are wet!!!! Why?

Tags: basement

The bottom 3 courses of my cinder block are wet and deteriorating (effervescence). The basement is waterproofed and it’s still happening.  Its on 2 interior walls and 1 exterior. The top layers of interior walls are dry. The top layers of exterior are also wet.  I live in Detroit Michigan and there’s been a lot of rain but this was going on before I had it water proofed as well.  The contractor said I do not need a sump pump.  I’m not near water. Can anyone help???[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Water may be coming in were block was laid on to footings were no sealer is used.and water table is that high.

Comment: What do you mean "the basement is waterproofed"? Sounds like something a contractor told you when they sold you something. But that said, clearly it is not waterproofed and generally,no basement ever is. There are NUMEROUS things that must be done to reduce and or move water away from entering the basement. In your case, it is still getting in there.

Comment: Plese share some pictures, and also tell us where you are, how the weather has been,what previous work has been done, do you have a sump pump? How has the weather been recently where you live?

Comment: You could add water proofing to inside of block for now.  Do you have gutters on the house? Is the house close to water or high water table .

Comment: Robert Moody how do I water proof inside the block?

Comment: The only basement I'm aware of that's waterproofed is Fukushima.  They drove a grid  of pipes under the foundation and ran Freon through them to freeze the ground solid.

Comment: Is this just a masonry paint or actually a cement based or silica based waterproofing paint on the block? Do you have what brand that was applied? Most waterproofing paints like Sta-Dri will not pop off the wall like that unless the wall was unstable before it was applied, them that has everything to do with the prep work

Comment: I think the paint  is coming off because of the moisture. Having said that part of the wall had been painted yellow originally and I think some of that had chipped off. I painted part with dry lock and I may have painted some with regular paint. I don’t recall.

Comment: @Harper, good thing I said generally; that is really really cool news. Hrmm is the basement waterproofed or is the substrate/bedding? Man, that is cool. (and expensive no doubt - to do, to maintain, and to operate). Robin, the wall looks wet form past (yellow dryer looking stain), and present, (off white stain) which seems to go up 5 rows or more. Thank you for these photos. We all have a water table and yours is probably just as high as mine is right now. So the water table may be a real issue for you.

Comment: Is there a chimney near this section of wall? (looking at the cleanout), what shape is the chimney in? Did your contractor install a tile cleanout capped port anywhere??? Might want to get it attached to a pump and open it to see if the table is an issue (dont do this on your own). A sump pump or external tile (or both) might be necessary and depending on your water table it could be futile. If there is an underground stream, broken pipes, etc, who knows. Or it could just be from a chimney. Do you live on a hill? bottom of a hill? Is your downspouts directed out to a street drain?

Comment: Noybman, lol I’m not sure about you’re saying. There is a chimney where the clean outs are but someone put conceete in them. Chimney is good. I live on a very little incline. I’m getting front of house regraded which I’ve been told will help.  The “yellow” stain is actually orange which I don’t understand. Downspouts do not lead to city drain but water pools outside of the house where the blocks are getting wet hence the regrade. Contractor who did waterproof said no need for sump pump as it drains into city connect.  Waterproofing has ports. I don’t think it’s the chimney.

Comment: From what you are telling us, you have a high water table, I'm guessing clay too, and cinderblock is not waterproof. Regrading is a good idea. You should have the chimney crown checked, even a little bit of a crack at all, unchecked, will let all of the rain in. As far as the comment on the lack of a sump pump "because it drains into the city connect" this makes no sense. You may still need to install a sump pump. It's not necessarily a bad thing! But grading, fixing chimney cracks and sealing it, and installing drains for downspouts are all cheap and smart, AND *WILL* help